# Django: Not fetching the same object

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a form where i am entering four details 'Persona Name', 'Persona Key' ,'Persona Key Label' and 'Persona Key Value' and on entering these values i am pressing Submit button which generates a GET request on my server.

Following are django views:-

```
def PersonaSave(request):
    persona_name = request.GET.get('persona_name',)
    persona_key = request.GET.get('key_name',)
    persona_key_value = request.GET.get('key_value',)
    persona_key_label = request.GET.get('key_label',)
    persona_submit = request.GET.get('Save',)
    return( persona_name , persona_key , persona_key_label , persona_key_value , persona_submit )

def TestPageView(request):
    x=PersonaSave(request)
    persona_name = x[0]
    persona_key = x[1]
    persona_key_label=x[2]
    persona_key_value=x[3]
    persona_submit=x[4]

    if(persona_name is None and persona_key is None and persona_key_label is None and persona_key_value is None):
        return render(request, 'dashboard/test_page.html')

    elif TestPersonaName.objects.filter(name=persona_name).exists():
        t= TestPersonaName.objects.get(pk=persona_name) 
        testpersona = TestPersona.objects.get(name=t)
        if testpersona.key == persona_key:
            testpersona.label= persona_key_label
            testpersona.value = persona_key_value


    t=TestPersonaName(name=persona_name)
    t.save()
    testpersona = TestPersona(name=t,key=persona_key,label=persona_key_label,value=persona_key_value)
    testpersona.save()

    return render(request,'dashboard/test_page.html')
```

I am rewriting codes of lines where updation and new persona formation starts to maintain the clarity of question.

**Update Function starts from here-----**

```
    elif TestPersonaName.objects.filter(name=persona_name).exists():
        t= TestPersonaName.objects.get(pk=persona_name) 
        testpersona = TestPersona.objects.get(name=t)
        if testpersona.key == persona_key:
            testpersona.label= persona_key_label
            testpersona.value = persona_key_value
```

**-----This is where update function ends**

If persona name is different then complete new TestPersonaName object and TestPersona object will be formed.

**For this the function starts here----**

```
    t=TestPersonaName(name=persona_name)
    t.save()
    testpersona = TestPersona(name=t,key=persona_key,label=persona_key_label,value=persona_key_value)
    testpersona.save()
```

**----and ends here.**

Now the problem is for the same persona name and same persona key two different TestPersona objects are being formed. For e.g If I enter persona_name = Ankit,
key = 'city' and value = 'New Delhi' and later i want to change city so i enter
name='Ankit' , key = 'city' and name = 'Lucknow'. On pressing submit two different TestPersona objects are being formed. i.e

```
  object1(name='Ankit',key='city', value='New Delhi') and 
  object2(name='Ankit',key='city',value='Lucknow')
```

**Ideally it should be:-**

```
   object1(name='Ankit', key='city', value='Lucknow')
```

Following are TestPersonaName and TestPersona models:-

```
class TestPersonaName(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,primary_key=True)


class TestPersona(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey('TestPersonaName',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    key  = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    label = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
elif TestPersonaName.objects.filter(name=persona_name).exists():
    t= TestPersonaName.objects.get(pk=persona_name) 
    testpersona = TestPersona.objects.get(name=t)
    if testpersona.key == persona_key:
        testpersona.label= persona_key_label
        testpersona.value = persona_key_value
```

You need too save the persona and `return` here as in the `if` above. Otherwise the interpreter exits this block and continues with

```
t=TestPersonaName(name=persona_name)
t.save()
testpersona = TestPersona(name=t,key=persona_key,label=persona_key_label,value=persona_key_value)
testpersona.save()
```

which replaces the value of `t` with a new persona that gets saved to DB. After every attempt to edit you'll keep ending up with a new record.

Comment: Thanks @4140tm. How could i forget this simple logic.